# SecurityException when running WorkplaceXT in local WebLogic

Tags: weblogic, jaas, filenet-p8, filenet-workplace

I need to run IBM Workplace XT to access a remote FileNet. I downloaded the installer and successfully created the .ear file. I also installed WebLogic 12.1.3 (development version for local testing). The deployment of `web_client.ear` runs fine, but after trying to login at `localhost:7001/WorkplaceXT` with the same WebLogic credentials, I get the `java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[admin, Administrators]` exception. I have read that I have to enable Cross-Domain Security, so I did following [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/security/EnableTrustBetweenDomains.html).

Didn't work, because after creating a new user and logging in with that, I get: `java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[newuser, CrossDomainConnectors]`

So, I tried giving some command-line arguments like so, as I have read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/secmg/domain.html#GUID-E574C257-DF5C-4042-9CA7-AE5BE56F5946), like so:

```
startWebLogic.cmd -Djavax.security.jacc.PolicyConfigurationFactory.provider -Djavax.security.jacc.policy.provider -Dweblogic.security.jacc.RoleMapperFactory.provider
```

It ended up giving other errors about not being able to find those classes, aside `weblogic.security.jacc.RoleMapperFactory.provider`. I tried launching `startWebLogic.cmd -Dweblogic.security.jacc.RoleMapperFactory.provider` only, but nothing.

Any idea is appreciated. Thank you in advance!